# How to show the name of category instead of its ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to have the category name show up in the Post's show.html.erb.

This is the current code for it:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @post.text %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Category:</strong>
  <%= @post.category_id %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @post.comments %>

<h2>Add a comment</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

How do I deal with this part: `<%= @post.category_id %>` so it can show the name of the category instead?

The current schema is:

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_posts_on_category_id", using: :btree
  end

  add_foreign_key "comments", "posts"
  add_foreign_key "posts", "categories"
end
```

Current models are:

Post:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :category

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :text, presence: true
end
```

Categories:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
```

Comment:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using association belongs_to in Post model, you can get the category name in your view this way:

```
<%= @post.category.name %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should access `@post`'s category's name:

```
@post.category.name
```